# Java Generic of Generic method

Tags: java, generics, casting, higher-kinded-types, parameterization

I wonder if it is possible to write a method that will handle casting of undefined types like:

**Precondition:**

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> l = List.of("value");
map.put("key", l);
```

**Method call:**

```
List<String> strings = convert("key", List.class, String.class);
```

**convert method itself:**

```
public <V, C extends Collection<V>> C<V> getCollection(String key, Class<C> collType, Class<V> objectType) {
    return (C<V>) map.get(key);
}
```

But statement C< V > doesn't compile and gives me an error: Type 'C' doesn't have type parameters.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not possible. Java does not support higher-kinded types.

Comment: Doesn't `(C)` work?

Comment: Java generics are a compile time "syntactic sugar" that allows safe checking of types.  Generic are literally erased at runtime -- all those generics are replaced with `Object` and the runtime doesn't know about the types you used (I think the compiler will insert a `(cast)` when needed for you).  If you need runtime type safety, look at the heterogeneous container pattern. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55737/typesafe-heterogeneous-container

Answer (score 1):

Java uses [target typing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types) in type inference which means the expected type on the right-hand side of an assignment can be leveraged for this purpose.

```
Map<String, Object> map = Map.of("strings", List.of("value"));
```

However, to take advantage of it an unchecked cast is needed:

```
<T> T convert(Map<String, Object> map, String key) {
    return (T) map.get(key);   // Warning: unchecked cast
}
```

You could then get the typed entry out of the map:

```
List<String> strings = convert(map, "strings");
```

However, because of type erasure of Java generics, the type parameter is not checked at runtime. So while this will throw a `ClassCastException`:

```
Set<String> setOfString = convert(map, "strings");
```

This will execute without any complaint, and you won't get a `ClassCastException` until you try to extract the values from the list:

```
List<Integer> numbers = convert(map, "strings");
```